# How to get an observable that changes whenever another observable changes

Tags: typescript, observable, rxjs5

### Problem

I have a service that looks like this:

```
DogService { 
    public getSelectedDog(): Observable<Uuid> {...}
    public getDog(dogUuid: Uuid): Observable<Dog> {...}
}
```

I would like to create an Observable that always contains my selected dog, ie `Observable<Dog>`.

---

### What I have tried so far

Currently what I am doing is this:

```
let selectedDog: Observable<Dog> =  dogService.getSelectedDog().flatMap( selectedDog => {
    return dogService.getDog( selectedDog );
});
```

Then you can subscribe to changes in the selected dog like this:

```
selectedDog.subscribe( dog => console.log( 'dog: ", dog.name, dog.mood );
```

Unfortunatly, this doesn't seem to work the way I expected it to.  The selectedDog observable only 
fires when the selectedDog has changed by not when the dog itself changes.

So for example lets say that we do the following:

```
const dog1: Dog = new Dog( '1',      // uuid
                           'Shadow', // name
                           'happy'   // mood
);

const dog2: Dog = new Dog( '2',      // uuid
                           'Barky',  // name
                           'Angry'   // mood
);


// Fires the getDog observable
dogService.addDog( dog1 );  

// Fires the getDog observable
dogService.addDog( dog2 );

// Fires the getSelectedDogObservable
dogService.selectDog( dog1.uuid )

// --- Now in console.log we will see: 'dog: Shadow happy'
```

Unfortunatly, if I update the dog, the console doesn't get logged to:

```
const updatedDog1: Dog = new Dog( '1',      // uuid
                                  'Shadow', // name
                                  'SAD'   // mood
                                   );
// Fires the getDog observable
dogService.updateDog( updatedDog1 );

// --- the console.log doesn't get invoked.  Crap.
```

**Question: How can I create `Observable<Dog>` that will fire whenever the selection or selected dog changes?**

Comment: For this to be answerable, you'll need to include the service implementation, as that's where the change is going to have to be made.

Comment: @cartant - I don't think that is true...

Comment: @cartant is correct I think as you will probably be using a subject in your service to update the rest of the observables

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, so I suspect a problem in your service. I have some code to demonstrate that in principle it should work.

One mistake you should correct though is that you are using `flatMap`, but should be using `switchMap`. The thing is that `flatMap` will merge every stream into your stream regardless of when you select a new dog, meaning you will keep getting updates of the previous selected dogs, which you don't want. So here is the code I was talking about:

```
var dogs = [
  Rx.Observable.timer(0, 500).map(() => 'barky'),
  Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).map(() => 'cuddles')
];

var selectedDog = 0;
var dogSelector = Rx.Observable
  .timer(0, 5000)
  .map(_ => {
    selectedDog = (selectedDog ? 0 : 1);
    return selectedDog;
  })
  .switchMap(i => dogs[i]);

dogSelector.subscribe(dog => console.log(`Doggy: ${dog}`))
```

http://jsbin.com/haqutehajo/1/edit?js,console

A new dog is selected every 5 second and each dog sends an update every 1 or half a second respectively. Also try `flatMap` instead of `switchMap` and you will see what I am talking about.